# How to use push notification in titanium for Android

Tags: android, notifications, push, titanium

I have worked some in Android and got to do some small apps in android. Now I am newly working in titanium. **I am stuck on how to do push notification in titanium for android?** The problem is even a little worse. I need to do push notification for all versions of android. As google is providing c2dm but it is only for v2.2 and above. I got to know something about urban airship but not sure that it could be used in titanium. Also to use urban airship we need to install a seperate app which is not fully recommended. Any support will be highly welcomed. Please response as quickly as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Rai,

It's not good form to ask, essentially, the same question in multiple ways. You need to read up on the titanium API, as I answered in [How to write android code in titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791988/how-to-write-android-code-in-titanium/4792073#4792073)